# Django not serving common static files

Tags: django

I've made a static folder in the root path of my project as it contains basic css/js which aren't tied to a specific app.

Project setup:

```
main
static
   css
      styles.css
accounts
```

#### settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
]
```

I have also installed `django.contrib.staticfiles`.

I have included files like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">`

But it doesn't seem to work and results in 404 error.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: try to hit **python manage.py collectstatic**

Comment: show your main urls.py code

Comment: Is PROJECT_ROOT what you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As visible from your directory structure, you are setting `staticfiles` as your static directory, when in fact the directory is `static`. Also, you need to use `BASE_DIR`, which is the directory in which your `manage.py` is located.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

should fix it.

`PROJECT_ROOT` is `BASE_DIR` + `settings.py` directory.